# How do I efficiently navigate the command line interface to Mathematica?

Tags: interface, command-line

I would like to perfom such feats as cycling through previous commands, editing commands in place, etc.  My expectation would be a readline-like interface, but this appears to not be the default.

Comment: Just curious: Why would you use the command line? Even for remote kernels, working with a frontend would be possible.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries sometimes configuring remote access can be painful, especially over ssh.

Comment: you could also just use emacs as a frontend for mathematica (there are modes for that)

Comment: @acl there are [modes](http://www.emacswiki.org/CategoryModes) for everything in emacs.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want *readline-like* behavior you can of course use a [readline wrapper](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/). This works on all operating systems. On Ubuntu Linux (and other distributions I'm sure too) it can be installed easily through the package management. On Max OSX this can be installed using for instance [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) and I'm sure, there is an easy option on Windows too. Anyway, on all systems you can compile it yourselft. The usage is then

```shell
rlwrap math
```

on Linux or

```shell
rlwrap /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathKernel
```

on Mac OSX. Try it and be surprised ;-)

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know about `rlwrap` (and I had the same experience as the OP when I tried the CLI out of curiosity).

Comment: @rm-rf sometimes I wonder whether it's because the most guys at Wolfram are Windows-guy. They really just give a <insert very rude word of your choice here> about the command line.

Comment: I used to use the kernel interface extensively, and for a while there, I got quite good at it. Of course, the notebook interface didn't exist when I started using mma, but that dates me a little to well, I think.

Comment: @halirutan I'd assume that this is because most people use the notebook interface for daily work. Then the command line interface doesn't get much love.

Comment: @halirutan: Thanks, I was able to build this from source and use it.

Comment: @halirutan in fact in Mathematica 9 there are some improvements in this regard. At least some things like cycling through history do work.

Answer (score 18):

If you're on Windows: which command line interface are you talking about?

The "math.exe" program is a console mode (i.e. "DOS prompt") interface to the Mathematica kernel.  If you use that, you have access to the standard Windows console command-line editing; it is automatically provided by the OS to all console mode programs.  You can use the arrow keys to move around in previous commands, and you can edit, insert, and delete, copy, cut and paste using the traditional DOS-style editing and function keys.

The "MathKernel.exe" program -- which is what appears as "Wolfram Mathematica 8 Kernel" in your Start Menu -- is a very simple GUI windowed interface without any line editing or other special features.

I usually use the Mathematica kernel by running "math.exe" inside a console, which I have set to be as tall as the screen and with a very large scrollback buffer (set using the console's "Properties" menu).

A LATER UPDATE: In Mathematica 9, the "math.exe" program uses a new and different keyboard editing system that it did before, one based on GNU readline.  But you can get rid of that and go back to standard Windows console command-line editing by removing or renaming the file `term.dll` in `$TopDirectory\SystemFiles\Kernel\Binaries\Windows` (32 bit) or `Windows-x86-64` (64 bit).

AN EVEN LATER UPDATE: `term.dll` is now in `$TopDirectory\SystemFiles\Libraries\Windows` or `...\Windows-x86-64`