# up arrow works in math version 9, fails in math version 8 ^[[A

Tags: version-9, version-8, command-line

I have strange up-arrow behavior on command line Mathematica 8 versus Mathematica 9.  Version 9 gives me history, where version 8 fails with escape codes.  Any way to make them both work on the same system?

```
ubuntu@ip-10-45-11-134:~$ math
Mathematica 9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2013 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= $KernelCount                                                                                                                                                               
    Out[1]= 0
    In[2]:= $KernelCount                                                                                                                                               
Out[2]= 0
In[3]:= ubuntu@ip-10-45-11-134:~$ math8                                                                                                                                            

Mathematica 8.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2011 Wolfram Research, Inc.
In[1]:= $KernelCount
    Out[1]= 0
    In[2]:= ^[[A
    In[2]:= 
    ubuntu@ip-10-45-11-134:~$
```

Comment: I confirm this behavior. In V6 up arrow also don't work. I think this is a feature of the V9.

Comment: @ybeltukov is right. This is a new feature in version 9, so there is no way to make version 8 behave in exactly the same way. However, one can obtain a reasonable approximation: [(11193)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11193/)

Comment: After more googling, there is a package called rlwrap that does the trick!

You can on ubuntu:

    apt-get install rlwrap

Then up-arrow behaves correctly on Ubuntu precise 13.04, at least:

    ubuntu@ip-10-45-11-134:~$ rlwrap math8

Comment: @bfschott Good catch! On Gentoo it also works fine. Could you post it as an answer? I will be possible to +1 you :)

Comment: @ybeltukov You might want to read my [answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11193/187) where I showed this. In the same post, [librik](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1638/librik) (working for Wolfram) explained that in version 9 they have linked the readline into the console math which makes that it works.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks! I've read your post a long time ago and totally forget it.

Comment: The answer might be a duplicate, but I think the original question is poorly phrased and hard to find.  "How do I efficiently navigate the command line interface in Mathematica" is hardly an indication that it will answer my question.